# Using Application insight API to extract telemetry data in web application

Tags: c#, azure

I wanted to extract users count from application insight inside my web application and was going through the document for the rest API
    https://dev.applicationinsights.io/
I am not sure if API response contains user count?If this is not the way is there a way to get data specifically user count from app insight?

Comment: what do you mean by users count? Number of people currently logged in? or Total users with accounts in the application?

Comment: Number of people currently logged in

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
GET /users/count
```

check the title 
[Metric metadata: getting a list of metrics](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/documentation/Using-the-API/Metrics) under Default metrics.

Comment: Thanks Train will try that

Comment: Hi,I tried the method however its not returning the correct user count.I a wondering how application insight knows about my internal logged in user.I think its not possible but any suggestion would be welcome

Comment: `users/authenticated` should return the number of currently authenticated users. Have you tried that? I believe `users/count` returns total number of users

Comment: thanks Yes I tried both user/count is giving total number of users but counting sessions also means if user is logged in via different browser its counting as different users.Users/authenticated is only checking if http request is authenticated or not.Both are not solving the purpose :)

Comment: Then the only way would be to use `sessions/count`, and not allow the user to have 2 sessions open, or force them to share the same session on the back end. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.